# Is it possible to call a method on an element that has not been loaded yet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, dom

I wrote [this small JQuery plugin to load content on a specific DOM element according to the hashchange](https://github.com/EricsonWillians/hashy-content), but I'm having problems making [MaterializeCSS's carousel](https://materializecss.com/carousel.html) work.

Here's home.html:

```
<div class="carousel">
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#one!">
        <img src="src/assets/carousel_slide_0.jpg">
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#two!">
        <img src="src/assets/carousel_slide_1.jpg">
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#three!">
        <img src="src/assets/carousel_slide_2.jpg">
    </a>
</div>
```

Here's my index.js:

```
import "materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js"
import "materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css"

import "styles/vovojo.less"
import "./hashy-content.js"

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".dropdown-trigger").dropdown({
        hover: true,
        constrainWidth: false
    });

    $("#content").addHash("index", "src/content/home.html");
    $("#content").addHash("quem-somos", "src/content/quem_somos.html");
    $("#content").addHash("contato", "src/content/contato.html");
    $().watch();
});
```

As I've attached the "index" hash to that "home.html" file, each time the hash changes to `#index`, the content of `home.html` gets loaded inside a "content" ID. Problem is, when the DOM of index.html is ready and the hash gets attached to that home.html, the `.carousel` element does not exist yet, so when the content gets loaded (jQuery.load()), the carousel doesn't work. If I associate a function to get called after the content has been loaded, I get all sorts of bugs regarding other dependencies.

So, Is it possible to apply a method on an element that has not been loaded yet? (To make a promise somehow / "wait")

Like:

$(document).whenNonExistentElementIsReady(function() {
    $("#NonExistentElement").doSomething();
});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might benefit from using jQuery.on().

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_on.asp

.on() method attaches events to FUTURE elements as well as currently-existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give Ringo's the right answer because it's right (When I've attached the "click" event to the body, I've managed to make the carousel work after the click). I've found a rather obscure solution to my specific problem, that I'll include here for future users:

```
$("#content").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function () {
    $(".carousel").carousel();
});
```

Now, each time the HTML/DOM structure of that element gets modified, the code runs (Which is exactly what I needed).

Comment: DOMSubtreeModified might be unreliable: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMSubtreeModified